# How do you have separate Ad Units of the same size in Google Ad Manager running different ads?

Tags: google-ad-manager

I justed created a second Ad Unit in Google Ad Manager, of the same size as a first one. They have separate Placements.

However the same ad banners are circulating in that second Ad Unit, and I don't want them to. I want to keep separate ads running so advertisers can choose which one to use. How do I do that? I assumed having 2 Placements would already keep them separate, but it doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have the following setup :

- Site Placement 1 allows 300x250 creative ad size
- Site Placement 2 allows 300x250 creative ad size
- Line Item 1 is delivering creative 1 which size is 300x250
- Line Item 2 is delivering create 2 which size is also 300x250

To make sure your Line Item 1 targets only the Placement 1 and Line Item 2 targets only the Placement 2, there are different options :

- add a different key-value on each placement and target it with your Line Items (see details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/188092?hl=en))

> Placement 1 key "position" = "atf", and your Line Item 1 targets position=atf
> Placement 2 key "position" = "btf", and your Line Item 2 target position=btf

- you can also declare incremental sizes (see details [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/4430844?hl=en))

> Placement 1 has 300x250 and 300x251 defined sizes and Line Item 2 targets 300x251 ad unit size
> Placement 2 has 300x250 and 300x252 defined sizes and Line Item 2 targets 300x252 ad unit size

Once your inventory is more detailed, you will be able to target Line Items more accurately.